# change url of address bar by .htaccess and load php

Tags: .htaccess

I want a .htaccess code to run test.php file from 
folder: `/public_html/folder/test.php` by type `example.com/test` in address bar instead of `example.com/folder/test.php`

link : http://example.com/folder/test.php

goal : http://example.com/test

Comment: What cant you mix? Can you post the rule that you tried to load files from the /my folder?